# How to access child iframe elements from a parent javascript page?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

In my page i have iframe code. When i click particluar link that i frame window enabled.it is a form.when i submit the form i get some hidden field values.how can i access those values in my parent page?.

Comment: Please show some code. Where are you submitting the form *to*?

Comment: <iframe name="signUp" id="signup" src="http://10.80.32.9:8080/app/appsignup.jsp" width="650" height="500"></iframe>

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
   var inter = setInterval(check,1000);
   function check(){
       if(window.frames['signUp'].document.getElementById('registrationstatus').value == "ok"){
    alert("welcome");
                         document.getElementById('appclose').style.display='block';
    clearInterval(inter);
   }
 }
  </script>

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728620/how-to-add-css-in-this-iframe

Comment: Is there any possibility to return to the parent page url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your iframe src= a complete url, and not a relative path (i.e: /app/appsignup.jsp) I am going to assume this Iframe exists at another IP or domain than the original page. If this assumption is correct, then you are not going to be able to modify the Iframe's DOM due to cross site scripting security rules in most browsers.

If the parent site, and child iframe exist on the same top level domain, then you can use document.getElementById("iframe_id")

Edit to answer second question:

You can add an onLoad event to the iframe, and so long as the iframe only has 1 form, and the page only changes when submitted, and this is where you want to be redirected.

Here is an example, but know this will redirect the first time and not work! 
What you will want to do is put a function in there, and then in the .js for that function check for the second onLoad...

```
<iframe name="signUp" id="signup" src="10.80.32.9:8080/app/appsignup.jsp"; width="650" height="500" onLoad="window.location('/index.html');">
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to return to the parent page url?

Comment: Updated answer to give some light. Sorry no examples, I will come back to this with more time if you need.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to access the iframe if it's on a different domain and/or port, as yours seem to be. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent that.

There may be a workaround, depending on your use case. Maybe add some more details.