# Get iframe id using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, iframe

I have below html.

### one.html

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="myFrame" src="test.html" width=100 height=100 frameborder=0 scrolling=no>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

both `one.html` and `test.html` are running on `different domains`. Is it possible to get an `iframe id` `inside test.html`?
I need to get iframe id value "myFrame" inside test.html.

Is it possible? Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473557/jquery-selector-for-element-inside-frame-with-same-origin

Comment: This is not possible as the content for the iframe is on a different domain to the containing window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5731131/2261259

Comment: @Rory is there any other alternate way that i can do ? Please help me.

Comment: @user755806 as you can see from shadow's link, there is no work around. It is a security feature of all browsers to prevent cross-site access via JS.

Comment: you may supposed to use window messaging